# Gradle processResources eachFile removing empty directories

Tags: gradle, directory, copy, rename

```
src/main/resources/foo/bar/a.xml
                   hello/world/b.xml
```

adding different prefixes for each file:

```
processResources {
    eachFile {details ->

       if (details.path.starts("foo/")) 
           details.path = "prefix1/" + details.path
       else
           details.path = "prefix2/" + details.path
    }
}
```

The problem is: the original directories are included in jar.

```
foo/
foo/bar
hello/
hello/world
```

It seems that eachFile iterates files excluding directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `includeEmptyDirs false` on `processResources`.